# Titanium Ti.Storekit on iTunes store: purchase works fine, but how do I 'consume' the product so it can be purchased again

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, storekit

I have the Ti.Storekit working nicely in the sandbox. Purchase works fine just as in the example code.

When I try to purchase an item a second time (say 1 ream of paper) the store says I already own it and refuses to sell me another.

How can I 'consume' this product to allow me to buy again?

Comment: Oh, gosh silly me. There was a line in the code I'd copied that says "Storekit.autoFinishTransactions = false;" well that needs to say 'True' and all is well for new transactions after that.